# I get error certificate too weak when trying to connect to server from python script. Is there any way to tell openssl to ignore this?

Tags: python, openssl, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to a bugzilla api from a python script. I'm using the requests module. The server is using old certificates and when I access from the chrome browser with the provided certificate I get a warning "site not secure" but it lets me access anyway.

This is my script

```
    payload = {'id': 'XXXXX', 'api_key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}
    r = requests.get('https://example.org/bugzilla/rest/bug', params=payload, verify=False, cert=('myCert.crt', 'myKey.key'))
```

And this is the end of the traceback I'm getting:

```
  File "C:\Workspace\programs\Python\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
  File "C:\Workspace\programs\Python\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 450, in load_cert_chain
    self._ctx.use_certificate_chain_file(certfile)
  File "C:\Workspace\programs\Python\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 908, in use_certificate_chain_file
    _raise_current_error()
  File "C:\Workspace\programs\Python\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_certificate', 'ca md too weak')]
```

Is there anyway to tell OpenSSL to ignore the fact that the certificate is not secure?

Comment: Do you really need to use cert signed with md5?

Comment: I think so, I tried to access without the certificate and I got this error: ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')])",). I tried to access to http:// instead of https:// I did not get a response.

Comment: First of all, are you sure that you need to use custom certificate at all?

Comment: I'm not really experienced in certificates so maybe I did not answer your question

Comment: Try to delete `verify` and `cert` arguments and launch script, maybe it'll be enough.

Comment: I get:  _File "C:\Workspace\programs\Python\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]_

Comment: It's weird. Try to upgrade certifi, `pip install --upgrade certifi` in console.

Comment: I've got certifi updated to the last version 2019.9.11

Comment: You can disable certificate verification using `verify=False`, but the fact that certificate verification have been failed is not good, somebody trying to spy on you :D